# Matching previous working date on website using selenium python

Tags: python, datetime

I defined two variables for previous days (one for friday and one for monday to thursday). After giving the condition, it asks for varible not defied, below is the code.

```
import datetime

d = datetime.date.today()

if d.weekday() == 0:
    tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    friday = d - tdelta
else:
    tdelta1 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    prev_day = d - tdelta1


if data_date == friday:
    print("Data as on", friday, "for page")   
elif data_date == prev_day:
    print("Data as on", prev_day, "for page")
else:
    print("Data update required.")
```

For the above code, error is shown as 'prev_day' not defined. Please help.

Comment: Where are you assigning value to `data_date` variable?

Comment: How is `datetime.date.today()` related to `Selenium`? Am I missing something?

Comment: data_date variable is created for converting the string on website to date